# Вечорами чи ввечері?

Tags: вживання-слів, прислівники

Власне, є наступне речення:
"Іноді (вечорами/ввечері) діти збираються на Станції." (переклад з російської "Иногда по вечерам дети собираются на Станции.")

Яке слово в даному випадку буде доречнішим і/або правильним? Мова йде про повторювану дію, тобто кожного вечора діти збираються на станції.

Не зміг знайти інформацію деінде, буду вдячний за допомогу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Ввечері/увечері](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=6878&page=252)* вживають частіше (наприклад, у ГРАК-10: 46806 *[ввечері/увечері](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=wordrow&word=%5B%D0%B2%D1%83%5D%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96)* проти 6300 *[вечорами](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)* проти 1792 *[вечором](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)* — і це при тому, що не всі трапляння *вечорами/вечором* у потрібному значенні). Однак *вечорами* теж цілком прийнятне. Його вживають такі видатні постаті як Шевченко, Марко Вовчок, Нечуй-Левицький, Франко тощо, наприклад:

> Уже й не бореться ні з ким, / А так собі гуляє / Та вечорами у садочок / До титаря вчащає (Тарас Шевченко, «Титарівна», 1848).
>
> Вечорами зграя коло криниці була гучніш, ніж ранками (Марко Вовчок, «Дев’ять братів і десята сестриця Галя», 1863).
>
> А паничі все налітали вечорами, а збірня й танці все не переставали (Іван Нечуй-Левицький, «Причепа», 1869).
>
> Незважаючи на утому і на здоров'я своє, вона не раз по роботі вечорами довго бродила по улицях, заким відшукала Івана дегоді в якім шинку (Іван Франко, «Борислав», 1877).

Так само, по-моєму, прийнятне *вечором*, хоча воно вживається ще рідше.

Також зазначу, що *ввечері/увечері* неможливо сполучити з прикметниками. «Теплим літнім вечором» або «теплими літніми вечорами», але не «тепле(?) літнє(?) ввечері/увечері». Тобто якщо Вам треба сполучити з прикметником, то варіант *ввечері/увечері* не підходить (хоч він найуживаніший без прикметників). Мабуть, на практиці *вечором* зараз уживається переважно саме з прикметниками (хоча я не бачу, що б забороняло вживати його без них, і зрідка воно вживається й без них); *вечорами* вживають і так, і так.

*Вечорами* дозволяє підкрестили багаторазовість дії. Але у Вашому випадку, мені здається, цілком прийнятно обійтися й без підкреслення. Тобто, можливо я щось не помічаю, але я не можу оголосити переможцем якийсь конкретний варіант у Вашому випадку:

- *ввечері/увечері*:

  - уживаніший варіант,
  - варіант, не притаманний російській мові (з іншого боку, я не вважаю це вагомим аргументом; можливо, варто захищати слова, які витісняються через вплив інших мов, але *ввечері/увечері* зараз і так найуживаніше);
- *вечорами*:

  - дозволяє врізноманітнити текст,
  - дозволяє підкреслити багаторазовість.

Comment: Дякую за вичерпну відповідь! Дуже корисно :)